# How to show messages with reason for skipped tests in teamcity?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, teamcity, junit4, teamcity-9.0

I run ui-automated tests (java+maven+junit4) on TeamCity. And there are some tests which are ignored for some reasons. So I'm trying to pass these reasons to teamcity results.
[How it looks on teamcity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRQ6n.jpg)

Tests are ignored via using Assume.assumeFalse - e.g.

```
Assume.assumeFalse("some message which I'd like to see on teamcity", false);
```

And then in the end there is special block for skipped tests

```
protected void skipped(AssumptionViolatedException e, Description description) {

        logger.info("##teamcity[testMetadata name='Reason' value='" + e.getMessage() +"']");
    }
```

Earlier I've tried use just logger.info with simple text, but it seems nothing is written to the log for skipped tests.
So I've tried the code above - pass message as metadata - it's feature available in the latest version of teamcity([More info there](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Reporting+Test+Metadata)), but it still didn't help.

Maybe anyone has some ideas how can I implement that? Or is it even possible?

Comment: What if you try logging the message with System.out.println instead of logger.info?

Answer (score 0):

If you would really like to ignore some tests then you should go for `@Ignore` Junit annotation. Reason could also be passed to this annotation as a parameter.

This annotation can be used to ignore test methods and whole test classes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707172/junit-ignore-usefulness) are some benefits to use this annotation.

To check, how to use this annotation, please refer following links:

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html

https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-3-ignore-test/